# Checking octave package version

Tags: octave

I installed the dataframe package in Octave and would like to programmatically  assert that the package version is at least 1.2.0. Does octave provide a way to check a package version programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Version = ver('dataframe')
% Version =
%   scalar structure containing the fields:
%     Name = dataframe
%     Version = 1.2.0
%     Release = [](0x0)
%     Date = 2017-08-14
```

Obviously `Version.Version` is still a string, but you can process that further, e.g. with `strsplit`, to obtain the major-minor-patch numbers.

```
strsplit( Version.Version, '.' )
% ans =
% {
%   [1,1] = 1
%   [1,2] = 2
%   [1,3] = 0
% }
```

Alternatively you can also use

```
Out = pkg('list', 'dataframe')
```

which also contains a 'version' field, as well as some extra information.

Comment: Instead of manually parsing the string version number, you can just use the `compare_versions` function, so something like this `compare_versions ((ver ("image")).Version, '2.8.0', '>')`